# Page Load series of events what kind data should be loaded :)

Tags: asp.net

hi anybody can help me what kind of data loaded  to improve performance of the website 
during below events i am not using below methods efficiently

- PreInit
- Init
- InitComplete
- PreLoad
- OnPreRender:java script can be binded
- Render
- Unload

  during above events  so that it would be great help for my
  developing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. PreInit : Dynamic control, master page etc can be set here
2. Init :Set initial/default value of control/properties. No viewstate can be used.
3. InitComplete : Set viewstate data.
4. PreLoad:  Set properties of controls.
5. OnPreRender: Again, last chance to set properties of controls.
6. Render: Put some HTML logic, kind of dynamically creating HTML.
7. Unload : Nothing much a developer should/can do here.

Comment: hi Milind,  you answer pretty good, but most cases we use prerender to set properties of the control in asp.net rest of the event we will not use munch

Comment: Shravan, I believe you wanted to understand what all can be done in various events in page life cycle and thats what I am trying to explain ! If your question was different, please edit and elaborate your question.